# WebAudio isn't giving any audio output

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener, web-audio-api, javascript-oscillator

***HTML***

```
<input type="range" onchange="play()" max=880 />
    <h2 id="fr">000hz</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="stop()">STOP</button>
```

***SCRIPT***

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
var gain = ctx.createGain();
osc.connect(gain);
gain.connect(ctx.destination);
gain.gain.value=0;
osc.start(0);
var f = document.querySelector("input");
f.addEventListener("input",(event)=>{
osc.frequency.value=event.target.value;
document.querySelector("h2").innerHTML = f.value + "hz"});
function play(){
  gain.gain.value = 1;
}
function stop(){
  gain.gain.value = 0;
}
```

There is no audio output but the frequency values do get logged on change and "fr" also gets updated.

Comment: I tried putting the code into a code snippet and it works fine. Are you seeing an error?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error, I have deployed the site here binaurmal.netlify.app and its not giving any audio output but yes it works remotely.

Comment: Now working thanks to a start button suggested by @not-a-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) is not allowed to start automatically.

It must be resumed (or created) after a [**user gesture**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) on the page

Try below sample code, you can do a modification accordingly.

```js
var ctx = new AudioContext();

var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
var gain = ctx.createGain();


function start() {

  osc.connect(gain);
  gain.connect(ctx.destination);
  gain.gain.value = 10;
  osc.start(0);

}


var f = document.querySelector("input");
f.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  osc.frequency.value = event.target.value;
  document.querySelector("h2").innerHTML = f.value + "hz"
});

function play() {
  gain.gain.value = 1;
}

function stop() {
  gain.gain.value = 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" onchange="play()" max=880 />

<h2 id="fr"></h2>
<button type="button" onclick="start()">START</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop()">STOP</button>
```